# Index out of range in if statement while actually it's not out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my second code ever in Python, which is a paper rock scissors game as learning training.
As you can see I tried to play with the `permutations` import and adventuring on my own out of the exercise given, till got the "Index Out of range Error" linked to the `if` statement.

```
from itertools import permutations
import random

options = ["rock","scissors","paper"]

perm = permutations(options,2)



x = 0
while x <= 10:
  def get_choices():
    print("Please choose enter a choice (Rock, Paper, Scissors): ",end="")    
    player_choice = input("")
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)
    #choice in random is an Atribute and note related to function naming
    choices = [player_choice, computer_choice]
    return choices

  result = get_choices()
  print("Results Player Vs PC",result)
  #print(list(perm)[1]) #for testing
  
  
  if result == list(perm)[0]:
   print("You've won")
  elif result == list(perm)[1]:
    print("You've lost")
  elif result == list(perm)[2]:
    print("You've lost")
  elif result == list(perm)[3]:
    print("You've won")
  elif result == list(perm)[4]:
    print("You've Won")
  elif result == list(perm)[5]:
    print("You've lost")
  else:
    print("Draw")
```

It tells me that the index of `list(perm)[0]` is out of range (even if it's 0). But it can't be. When I print the list, it goes fine and shows all the possible results of the permutation.

Comment: Aaaah i see why it pass list(perm)[0] then crash!!!!
is there any  alternative to keep the data stored in perm?

Comment: Maybe just assign `list(perm)` to a variable once and then use that instead of trying to create a list over and over again.

Comment: I can't exactly reproduce error at list(perm)[0], but FYI permutations return an iterator object (a generator), once you convert to list, it become empty. So you should follow @Mark suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After executing the "list" function, the "perm" object is empty.

```
   from itertools import permutations

   options = ["rock","scissors","paper"]

   perm = permutations(options,2)
   print(any(perm),perm is None)   #output:True False
   list(perm) 
   print(any(perm),perm is None)   #output:**False** False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).